# Can't get bot to work in azure from vs publish

Tags: azure, deployment, frameworks, bots, chatbot

I have a bot written in c# in visual studio, when I publish it to azure via visual studio an app service is set up but I don't know what the next step is to get the bot to work in test. I've tried to deploy a bot channel registration and populate the app service with the new app I'd and password but this doesn't seem to work. In test in azure it won't send the messages

I've also tried deployment via an empty bot deployed to azure as per the ms docs,  this doesn't work either.

Has anyone got experience of this process? , I've googled extensively but all the help is old. I'm sure I'm just misinterpreting something but it's the first time I've done it and can't tell.

Any advice or links are appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks you this was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that your bot can run on your local environment. I am using the [Bot Framework Emulator](https://aka.ms/Emulator-wiki-getting-started) to test my local bot. I referred to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-sdk-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to create a bot with vs2017.
[image]

Then, create a web bot on Azure portal.
[image]
[image]

When it is deployed, download the bot source code, and extract the contents of the download zip file to a local folder. We need the settings under PostDeloyScripts folder.
[image]

Now, you can publish your own bot by using that settings. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#publish-c-bot-on-app-service-plan-from-visual-studio) for more details.
[image]

After all these steps, we can use the bot published to azure.
[image]